# ioremap() fails due to precompiled device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning linux device drivers and kernel in general and wanted to write a device driver to control the GPIOs on the platform of my choice which is Raspberry pi 4.
I stumbled onto the kernel function **ioremap()** which maps physical addresses to virtual addresses which my code can then access through special functions like **readb(),writeb() etc..**.

The issue is that the memory address for the GPIO registers is already allocated to another driver (possibly the linux standard GPIO driver?) so any call to ioremap() fails.

The dump of /proc/iomem leads to this:

```
00000000-3bffffff : System RAM
  00008000-00ffffff : Kernel code
  01200000-0138e8e7 : Kernel data
fd580000-fd58ffff : fd580000.ethernet ethernet@7d580000
  fd580e14-fd580e1c : unimac-mdio.-19
fe007000-fe007aff : fe007000.dma dma@7e007000
fe007b00-fe007eff : fe007b00.dma dma@7e007b00
fe00a000-fe00a023 : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
fe00b840-fe00b87b : fe00b840.mailbox mailbox@7e00b840
fe00b880-fe00b8bf : fe00b880.mailbox mailbox@7e00b880
fe100000-fe100113 : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
fe101000-fe102fff : fe101000.cprman cprman@7e101000
fe104000-fe10400f : fe104000.rng rng@7e104000
fe200000-fe2000b3 : fe200000.gpio gpio@7e200000
fe201000-fe2011ff : serial@7e201000
  fe201000-fe2011ff : fe201000.serial serial@7e201000
fe204000-fe2041ff : fe204000.spi spi@7e204000
fe215000-fe215007 : fe215000.aux aux@7e215000
fe215040-fe21507f : fe215040.serial serial@7e215040
fe300000-fe3000ff : fe300000.mmcnr mmcnr@7e300000
fe340000-fe3400ff : fe340000.emmc2 emmc2@7e340000
fe600000-fe6000ff : fe600000.firmwarekms firmwarekms@7e600000
fe804000-fe804fff : fe804000.i2c i2c@7e804000
fe980000-fe98ffff : fe980000.usb usb@7e980000
fec00000-fec03fff : fec00000.v3d hub
fec04000-fec07fff : fec00000.v3d core0
fec11000-fec1101f : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
```

which indicated that something has already remapped fe200000-fe2000b3.

How do I remove that/block the driver so that I free up that memory range and can write and test my own drivers?

Comment: You risk breaking other drivers if you disable the existing/installed gpio driver.  Your post reads like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @sawdust Then is their any way to get access to the same MMIO region?

Comment: moreover i dont see any other drivers using it.

Comment: You may alter the Device Tree for that.

Comment: Rebuild the kernel with the existing GPIO driver configured off or as a module that can be unloaded.

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"moreover i dont see any other drivers using it."* Other drivers may be using (as a GPIO descriptor consumer) the GPIO lines exposed by the GPIO controller.